# How to connect to Neo4j 3.0 database with neo4j-jdbc?

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, neo4j

**Hi,**

I've created a maven project in eclipse and added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm just trying to get a connection to my db working so that I can move on to integrate the connection with my main project but I'm having trouble getting things off the ground.

I've used the code example given on the official repo:

```
import org.neo4j.jdbc.Connection;
import org.neo4j.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import org.neo4j.jdbc.ResultSet;

public class Neo4jConnectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Connect
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                        "jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost");

        // Querying
        String query = "MATCH (u:User)-[:FRIEND]-(f:User) 
                        WHERE u.name = {1} 
                        RETURN f.name, f.age";
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1,"John");
            ResultSet rs = con.execute();

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Friend: "+rs.getString("f.name")+" is "+rs.getInt("f.age"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        con.close();
    }
}
```

I am unable to compile this as:

`DriverManager` cannot be resolved within the neo4j-jdbc-3.0,

`Prepared stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);` causes a type mismatch,

and `con.execute()` is undefined for type `org.neo4j.jdbc.Connection`

**I'd greatly appreciate any advice and expertise on the matter, thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DriverManager`, `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` are all classes or interfaces from the `java.sql` package, which is part of the JDK. I guess the documentation assumes you'll use an IDE which will find the correct import for you.

It's the point of using the JDBC driver: you use the JDBC API, not a proprietary one (i.e. in a vendor package).

---

**Update**

There was a typo in the neo4j-jdbc readme, it should have read

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.execute();
```

instead of

```
ResultSet rs = con.execute();
```

otherwise the `PreparedStatement` has not use (and the code doesn't compile because there's no no-arg overload of `Connection.execute()`).

---

**Update 2**

The documented dependency was also wrong, as `neo4j-jdbc` does not contain any driver.

You should depend on:

- either the all-in-one module, which gives you the opportunity to use the Bolt or HTTP protocols:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- or the module for a specific protocol:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-bolt</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- or -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-http</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

---

**Update 3**

Both problems have now been fixed in the documentation of the project.

Comment: After making those changes `con.execute` is still undefined (I commented this out in order to make it runnable). After running the code it throws an SQLException `No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost`. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: For completeness, I've updated the answer with both code and dependency fixes.

Comment: I tried to test this and made the suggested changes but I'm still unable to establish a connection. This [JDBCTest](http://pastebin.com/njT0kjJ0) is what I used and includes the error message thrown by the SQLException. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: Like the message says, your JDBC URL is wrong (it was OK in the question above): you have `bolt/localhost` instead of `bolt://localhost`. You don't need to specify the port if you use the default one.

Answer (score 2):

By changing to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to successfully connect to the Neo4j 3.0 server using an example from Neo4j's site:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( 
        "bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "neo4j" ) );
    Session session = driver.session();

    session.run( "CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})" );

    StatementResult result = session.run( 
                                        "MATCH (a:Person) 
                                         WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' 
                                         RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title");

    while ( result.hasNext() ) {
        Record record = result.next();
        System.out.println( record.get( "title" ).asString() + 
                                " " + record.get("name").asString() );
    }

    session.close();
    driver.close();
}
```

**I thought I'd share as this worked instantly with no hassle.**

[Neo4j Language Guides](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/)